# Paired sample, quasi-matched controls, and a covariate - ANCOVAs in R?

Tags: r, t-test, ancova, paired-data

I have been going around in circles on this question for a while, so figured I'd resort to the expertise on stackexchange.

My data: I have performance on a multitude of functional tests taken at 2 time points (before and after surgery). I also have the performance of a quasi-matched set of  healthy controls (mean age and BMI are matched to the patient population). I would like to see how function changes following surgery, if it matches levels of controls, but I would especially like to account for the improvements in pain between time-points of the patient population. I have a self-report pain score at each time point.

My gut feeling is to run independent t-tests between post-op and control function, paired t-tests between pre- and post-op, and then an ANCOVA for pre- to post- improvements, using the pain score as the covariate.  However, I am not sure if this is the correct track? If it is, should I be correcting for multiple comparisons? And then, my big question, is how to run the ANCOVA in R? I've read numerous walk-through tutorials but I can't seem to apply them to this situation.

I guess in other words, for the patient data: I want to see if there is any improvement in function if we remove the effect of improvement in pain.

Any suggestions/points in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*ANCOVA for pre- to post- improvements*" Can you explain what is being compared here? What is going into the model that is different from your proposed paired t-test?